# Cannot get phabricator to send email notifications for workboard changes

Tags: email, notifications, phabricator

I installed phabricator using the bitnami installer [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/phabricator).  I was able to set up email notifications by setting the config to use SMTP with a gmail address.  This works fine for things like registration, or sending test emails.  However, it seems no matter what I do, nobody on our team ever gets email notifications for changes to our workboard.  For example, when assigning a task, changing the name of the project, etc.

I have confirmed that everyone is 'watching' the project, and that the project has mail enabled, but still no dice.  Right now we're using phabricator version as of (July 30 2016) however I also tried the latest version (Dec 2016) and encountered the same problem.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this issue would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  If you're getting similar errors, you can debug it by running `bin/mail list-outbound`.  In my case this showed "Delivery Failed".  Then you can output errors for an individual email attempt with `bin/mail show-outbound` and specify the id.

In my case the issue was that I didn't set the `metamta.domain` propery correctly